# how can i convert django app to desktop app

Tags: python, django, electron, pyinstaller, desktop-application

I have a Django app up and running on DigitalOcean with Nginx and PostgreSQL. But some clients want an offline version of the app so that their data remains on their systems and they don't have to connect to the internet. One solution is to write the whole app from scratch but that would take time and cost.

I was thinking of a solution where I can convert the Django app into a desktop app with minimal changes i.e. replace CDNs with files and remove functionality that requires internet. But I don't know how can I do this.

I was thinking of electron, i,e, elctron will spawn a child process which will start django's server and then the electron will load `127.0.0.1:8000` in a webview.
But how can I package this app into an executable because it would need python installed and configured on the user's system. Or does python itself has any library that can convert the Django app into a desktop app?

Below is the file structure of my Django project

```
project_folder/
    app_1/
    app_2/
    app_3/
    configurations/
        templates/
        __init__.py
        asgi.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    media/
    staticfiles/
    manage.py
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need Electron for this task? Just create a script starting the Django server and launching the user's default web browser... After all, your app already is browser-ready, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner thanks for the feedback but it would need python installed on the user's system. I want a single executable with all the dependencies without needing to install python. Also, it is a desktop app so opening it on a web browser doesn't feel promising :)

Comment: Will [this](https://www.todesktop.com/works-with/django) work?

Comment: Please tell me if it helps!

Comment: @jjoa already seen it! it just opens a web view in electron, but my requirement is to get a complete offline version of the app

Comment: suffering from same situation Did you get any solution?